# How to disable/block Microsoft Store on Windows 10 Pro by firewall?

Tags: windows, firewalls, microsoft, registry, gpo

I want to block Microsoft Store on Windows 10 pro in a corporate environment. Having read relevant articles about this matter and tested on my machine, I see that Windows 10 Pro does not support this function (either through Group Policy [not recommended by my Manager] or Registry.

Now, I opt for another solution, that is, blocking it by firewall. If it is feasible, can anyone show me the rules how to block Microsoft Store by firewall? I'm using a tool to configure this rule.

Comment: Are you sure you checked this?

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/a8405957-5025-427e-9405-331b1a8dde21/uninstall-or-disable-the-microsoft-store

Comment: @Elhitch Yes, including testing on my computer. Keep in mind that the target Windows is 10 Pro, which Microsoft no longer support for disabling Miscrosoft Store (see [link]  (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135657/can-t-disable-windows-store-in-windows-10-pro-through-group-policy).

Comment: If you mean via the on-network firewall, this is going to fail if the machine (whatever it is) is taken off the network.  Also, note that if you're handing these out to developers, there may be tools that are only available via the windows store (WSL, for example - although since only the front end was disabled I could still use other ways....)

Comment: What firewall are you hoping to use? The built-in windows firewall? You know that blocking programs is a built-in rule feature?

Answer (score -1):

Im not sure on how you are planning to block the application through firewall. I believe you can only block the traffic from "windows store" using firewall.

But, this can be done by any application control program or AV(If the AV has an Application control feature).
you can configure the application control program to block the execution of WinStore.App.exe (main process of windows store application).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked.